# MongoDB - Set if Null or Empty Query Operator

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if there exists a `$setIfNullOrEmpty` operator. I'm currently using an upsert like this:

```
const filter = {
    id: 123
}
const updates = {
    $set: {
        varx: valx
    },
    $inc: { vary: valy },
    $setOnInsert: z
};
const options = { upsert: true };
collection.updateOneWithOptions(filter, updates, options);
```

I would like to also have an option to `$set` some value if in the database it's null or an empty string. My ideal `updates` object would look like this (does something like this exist?):

```
const updates = {
        $set: {
            varx: valx
        },
        $setIfNullOrEmpty: {
            varxy: varxy
        }
        $inc: { vary: valy },
        $setOnInsert: z
    };
```

I understand that I could make 2 queries (1 to grab the item I'm looking for, check for that property and another to update the item) but I'm looking for a way to make 1 query. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This can be achieved using $cond operator

Try the below command

```
const filter = {
    id: 123
}
const updates = {
    $cond: {
        if: {
            $or:[{$eq: ["varxy",null]},{$eq: ["varxy",""]}]
        },
        then: {
            $set: {
                varxy: varxy
            }
        },
        else: {
            $set: {
                varx: valx
            }
        }
    },
    $inc: { vary: valy },
    $setOnInsert: z
};
const options = { upsert: true };
collection.updateOneWithOptions(filter, updates, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/):

> The $inc operator increments a field by a specified value.
>
> If the field does not exist, $inc creates the field and sets the field
>   to the specified value.

So your current query works. If the found document doesn't have field `vary`, it would be created and set with your specified value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I don't think that answers the question. I'm looking for a `$set` that would work if the field was null or empty. The `$inc` works only with integers and will only set the field if it doesn't exists. Not if the field is null or an empty string.